# GROUP_CONCAT to concat results from one table and not all?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use MySQL to concatenate results from an intermediary table, but it seems that the results are truncated to a single row? Here is my query so far.

Note, collections and tags are both many to one for products, i.e., each product may belong to multiple collections and have multiple tags.

```
SELECT products.id,name,price,GROUP_CONCAT(collections.collectionname)
FROM products 
JOIN collections on products.id = collections.product_id
JOIN tags on tags.external_id = products.id
WHERE tag = 'search term'
```

```
= products 
id
name
price

= collections
id
collectionname
product_id

= tags
id
tag
external_id
```

Comment: 'If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample , your actual result and your epxected  result  ..

Comment: Adding `GROUP BY products.id` should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks @Nick and P.Salmon - the additional group by in the end was what i needed and wasn't understanding!